# how to flip the case of a Chars within a certain range

Tags: scala, junit

I wish to learn how to flip the case of a Chars within a certain range within a string builder. given a lower and upper bound that lies somewhere in between 0 to StringBuilder.length.

Comment: Hi sheckleberg, the right way to mark a question as solved on Stack Overflow is to click the check-mark next to the answer that best solved your problem, not to edit the title to say "solved."

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you build the string you want first, then simply `replace()`.

```
val buff = new StringBuilder("XxXThis iS tHE tEXTXxX")
val (lwr,upr) = (3,19)

val str = (lwr until upr).map{ x => buff(x) match {
    case c if c.isLower => c.toUpper
    case c              => c.toLower
  }
}.mkString
buff.replace(lwr, upr, str)  //res0: StringBuilder = XxXtHIS Is The TextXxX
```